# Count number of words that end with specific letter

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

I have a list of books inside a directory which I'm reading from and I want to list all words from the books that end with the lower and uppercase of a specific letter.

There's probably a way of doing it using cut or tr but I just can't think about it. Is there a way to use globs inside the pipe for it?

I'm not allowed to use grep, sed, awk, or perl.

Edit: The closest I got was:

`cat * | tr '[:punct:]' ' '|  tr ' ' '\n' | tr -s '\n'|  tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | rev  | sort`

With this I can have the list of all words, one in each line. We don't really need to get rid of duplicates. Now I would just need to filter the words that have q in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
< book.txt \
  tr -sc '[:alnum:]_-' '[\n*]' |
  tr -d - |
  rev |
  cut -c1 |
  tr -cd eE |
  fold -w1 |
  sort |
  uniq -c
```

To count the `e`s and `E`s at the end of words (here defined as sequences of alphanumericals or underscores or hyphens), but note some of the limitations:

- with many implementations including the GNU ones, that only works for single-byte characters.
- `rev`, though common is not a standard command.
- `USA` would be one word and `U.S.A.` three words.
- even with implementations that work correctly with characters, it would count 2 `e`s in `Stéphane` if the `é` was written in its decomposed form (`e` followed by U+0301 the combining acute accent).
- it doesn't handle hyphenation.
- it would count one `e` in 1.02e+23 or 0xffe.5fp-4...

If you were restricted to the POSIX shell and utilities, you could also use `ed`:

```
ed -s book.txt << 'EOF' | sort | uniq -c
g/[^[:alnum:]_-]\{1,\}/s//\
/g
g/-/s///g
g/.*\(.\)$/s//\1/
v/[eE]$/d
,p
Q
EOF
```

Or with `sh`:

```
l=0 u=0
< book.txt \
  tr -sc '[:alnum:]_-' '[\n*]' | {
    while IFS= read -r word; do
      word=${word%"${word##*[!-]}"}
      case $word in
        (*e) l=$((l + 1));;
        (*E) u=$((u + 1));;
      esac
    done
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$l" e "$u" E
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Why did you use fold for? I edited my main post with my partial solution. There's no problem considering U.S.A as three words.